# Order of a subgroup formula

Tags: abstract-algebra

So I need to proof For cyclic group G of order n with a generator g, then 
for $x = g^m \in G$ we have |x| = $n/gcd(n,m)$. However I seem to have something wrong in my proof.  Suppose gcd(n,m) = d

I am using the following lemma to help me in my proof If |a| is finite, then m = |a| is the least integer such that $a^{m} = e$

I will show that first that $x^{n/(n,m)} = e $

1) $x^{d} = (g^m)^{n/d} = g^{m * n/d} = g^{m/d * n} = (g^{n})^{m/d}$ notice that 
$m/d \in Z$ by definition.

2) So now I need to show that n/d is the least integer such that $x^{n/d} = e $
I am trying to prove by contradiction by assuming that there exists $k < n/d$ such that x^k = e, but however I am not getting a contradiction.

by division algorithm $n/d = t \in Z$

$t = kq + r \rightarrow x^t  = (x^k)^q * x^r  = e^{q} * x^r = x^r$

So we have $x^t = x^r$ so r must be zero since k is the smallest integer such that 
$x^k = e $ but I don't get any contradiction this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your definition of the order of an element is missing one important feature.  The [order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_%28group_theory%29) of an element $g$ is the smallest **positive** integer $n$ such that $g^n = e$.  (If no such integer exists, then $g$ has infinite order.)  So no element can have order $0$.

**EDIT:** In response to your comment, I would instead use the following argument.  Let $d = \gcd(n,m)$ and write $n = dt$ and $m = du$.  Note that $t$ and $u$ are relatively prime.  Suppose that $|x| = k$ for some $k \leq t$; we show that $k = t$.  Since $x^t = e$, then $k \mid t$.  Now $e = x^k = g^{mk}$, so $n \mid mk$, i.e., $dt \mid duk$.  Then $t \mid uk$ and since $t$ and $u$ are relatively prime, then $t \mid k$.  Then $t$ and $k$ are positive integers that divide each other, hence $k = t$.

Comment: So I see in this case we get that $g^{n/d}$ must be 0 it can't be positive integer by the argument above and so it will be infinite order which is contradiction to the statement that G is cyclic group of order n right?

Comment: @KarimMansour I've edited to address your question.

Comment: Thanks alot SpamIAm that makes perfect sense.